# How to show composition of Sigmoid function and $\log x + \alpha$ is concave?

Tags: derivatives, curvature

Let $\textbf{Sigmoid}(x) = \sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. How can we show $\textbf{Sigmoid}(y)$ is concave where $y=\log x + \alpha$ and $\alpha\geq 0$?

**My try:**

We know $\sigma'(x)=\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))=\sigma(x)\sigma(-x)$. Also, we know 
$$
\textbf{Sigmoid}'(y)=\sigma'(y)=y'\sigma'(y)=\frac{1}{x}\sigma'(y)=\frac{1}{x}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)
$$

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf{Sigmoid}''(y)=\sigma''(y)&=(\frac{1}{x}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y))'\\
&=-\frac{1}{x^2}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)
+ \frac{1}{x}y'\sigma'(y)\sigma(-y)
+\frac{1}{x}\sigma(y)(-y)'\sigma'(-y)\\
&=
-\frac{1}{x^2}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)
+ \frac{1}{x^2}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)\sigma(-y)
-\frac{1}{x^2}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)\sigma(y)\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\sigma(y)\sigma(-y)
\Big(
-1
+ \sigma(-y)
-
\sigma(y)
\Big)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since both $\sigma(y)$ and $\sigma(-y)$ are positive and $x>0$, we need to find the sign of the last term.

**Please to answer my question in limit sense or intuitively, I want to show the last parentheses is negative.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-1 + \sigma(-y) - \sigma(y)&=-1+\frac{1}{1+e^{y}} - \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}\\
&= -1 + \frac{1+e^{-y}}{(1+e^{y})(1+e^{-y})} - \frac{1+e^{y}}{(1+e^{y})(1+e^{-y})}\\
&=-1 + \frac{e^{-y}-e^{y}}{(1+e^{y})(1+e^{-y})} \\
&=
\frac{-1 -e^{-y} -e^{y} -1 + e^{-y}-e^{y}}{(1+e^{y})(1+e^{-y})}\\
&=\frac{-2-2e^{y} }{(1+e^{y})(1+e^{-y})}
\end{split}
\end{equation}